# Excel でフィルター状態を維持し、可視セルのみ貼り付けたい

Tags: excel

## やりたいこと

sheet2に入っている値をsheet1フィルターしている状態で貼り付けたいです。
下記の手順で行っています。

1. sheet2の2行目まで選択してCtrl+Cでコピする。
2. sheet1を Bの列　フィルター１で行う
3. C列をフィルターした状態で選択して［可視セル］を選んで［OK］を押す。
4. Ctrl+Vで貼り付けをする。

下記の結果になります。

sheet1 Bの列　フィルター１でした状態

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | 1 | 5 |
| Albania | 1 | 5 |

ここまでOKですが、フィルターを外すと下記のようになります。

## 現在の結果

sheet1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | 1 | 5 |
| Atlanta | 2 | 5 |
| Argentina | 3 |  |
| Albania | 1 | 5 |
|  |  | 5 |

なぜこのような結果になりますか。
フィルターした状態で、貼り付け方法が間違っていますでしょうか。

## 処理内容

sheet1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | 1 |  |
| Atlanta | 2 |  |
| Argentina | 3 |  |
| Albania | 1 |  |

sheet1 Bの列　フィルター１で行う

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | 1 |  |
| Albania | 1 |  |

sheet2
1行目と2行目には５入っています。

| A |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 5 |

実現したい内容
sheet1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | 1 | 5 |
| Atlanta | 2 |  |
| Argentina | 3 |  |
| Albania | 1 | 5 |

Comment: プログラミングと関係の無い、単純な Excel に関する質問はオフトピックと判断される可能性があります。

Comment: @cubick 単純な操作に関する質問ではありますが、VBAにおいてもExcel操作と同じ動作をするため、プログラミングの話題としても本質問は有意義と考えます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

フィルター状態は関係ありません。Excelのセルのコピーに関する仕様です。

ExcelはRangeという単位で処理されています。Rangeは歯抜けのない四角形の領域となります。

今回、コピー元は2行1列のRangeとなります。貼り付け先は飛び地になっているので1行1列のRangeが２つ選択された状態となります。
ExcelではRangeの行列が同じサイズであればそのまま貼り付けられますが、今回はサイズが異なるため該当しません。
別のルールとして、貼り付け先のRangeが1行1列の場合、そこを左上としてそれぞれに貼り付けが行われます。今回はこれに該当しています。

解決策としては、コピー元を1行1列（つまり単一のセル）とすることです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。